# Text cutoff in Plotly subplot, Python

Tags: python, plotly, bar-chart

I am trying to make a subplot with 4 bar plots to show the distributions for 4 categorical variables. I want each of these bars to show their value above them. For this I am trying a code which is similar to this one -

```
fig = make_subplots(rows = 2, cols = 2, shared_yaxes = True)

bar_fig1 = go.Figure()
bar_obj1 = go.Bar(x = x1, y = y1, text = y1, textposition = "outside")
bar_fig1.add_trace(bar_obj1)
fig.add_traces(bar_fig1.data, rows = 1, cols = 1)

bar_fig2 = go.Figure()
bar_obj2 = go.Bar(x = x2, y = y2, text = y2, textposition = "outside")
bar_fig2.add_trace(bar_obj2)
fig.add_traces(bar_fig2.data, rows = 1, cols = 2)

bar_fig3 = go.Figure()
bar_obj3 = go.Bar(x = x3, y = y3, text = y3, textposition = "outside")
bar_fig3.add_trace(bar_obj3)
fig.add_traces(bar_fig3.data, rows = 2, cols = 1)

bar_fig4 = go.Figure()
bar_obj4 = go.Bar(x = x4, y = y4, text = y4, textposition = "outside")
bar_fig4.add_trace(bar_obj4)
fig.add_traces(bar_fig4.data, rows = 2, cols = 2)

fig.show()
```

Using the above code I get a graph that looks like this -

[image]

As you can see, some of the bars have the text above them cut off. How can I fix this?

Comment: Try > use the `cliponaxis: false` option \
Text is cut off on bars where textposition=outside · Issue #2001 · plotly/plotly.js
https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/2001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't present any data, I created a subplot with the numbers I read from the image; specifying a range for the y-axis would prevent the annotation at the top of the graph from being cut off. Your code sets `go.Figure()` for each subplot unit, but it is not necessary to set it each time. It is in the form of adding to the first configured fig.

Additional note:
In the subplots of plotly, each y-axis is given a separate name: ' yaxis','yaxis2','yaxis3'... You could write code for each y-axis separately, but we have simplified it by using the implicit notation. To see the data structure of the graph, check `fig.data`.

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

x1 = [3,1,2]
y1 = [491,213,184]
fig = make_subplots(rows = 2, cols = 2, shared_yaxes = True)

fig.add_traces(go.Bar(x=x1, y=y1, text=y1, textposition = "outside"), rows=1, cols=1)
fig.add_traces(go.Bar(x=x1, y=y1, text=y1, textposition = "outside"), rows=1, cols=2)
fig.add_traces(go.Bar(x=x1, y=y1, text=y1, textposition = "outside"), rows=2, cols=1)
fig.add_traces(go.Bar(x=x1, y=y1, text=y1, textposition = "outside"), rows=2, cols=2)

fig.update_layout({'yaxis'+str(i+1): dict(range=[0,650]) for i in range(4)})

fig.show()
```

[image]

If y-axis range is not specified

[image]

Comment: Thanks, changing the range to [0,750] worked! I am setting go.Figure() to each subplot because I need to customize each bar graph to my wishes and that was the only way I could. Is there any other way I should use?

Comment: For example, what would you like to do?